# Can I set cross-axis size of a flex box item to a percentage of container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three elements aligned horizontally in a flex box of set width and I would like the flex box to take the cross-axis size (height) of the largest of two of them and for the third to take 80% of that size. Is this possible?

[Code pen here](https://codepen.io/anfedorov/pen/dRoexw?editors=1100).

```
^ code
```

Comment: Do you want to give size to  boxes inside a flex container ?

Comment: no, they vary. in particular, the rightmost box sets the height via variable content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by either set the `separator` to absolute, or like below, where I used a pseudo, which IMHO is better if it is only going to be as a seperator.

In addition to the `itemBody::before` rule, I also added `position: relative` to the `itemBody` so the pseudo's absolute position relates to it.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anfedorov/pen/yXYBRK?editors=1100)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.iconHolder {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
}

.itemBody {
  position: relative;          /*  added property  */
  width: 269px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
.itemBody::before {            /*  added/changed rule/properties  */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  height: 80%;
  min-height: 45px;
}

.text {
}

.date {  
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  
  <div class='iconHolder'>
    X
  </div>
    
  <div class='itemBody'>
    <div class='text'>
      Howdy there, this is some text that goes in
      the item body! It might be very long and will
      need to stretch the cross axies of the outer
      flex box. When this happens, I'd like the separator
      bar to grow with it!
     </div>
    <div class='date'>about 3 days ago</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

---

Here with the existing markup.

In addition to make the `separator` positioned absolute, I also added `position: relative` to the `container` so the `spearator`'s absolute position relates to it.

```
.separator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 38px; 
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  height: 80%;
  min-height: 45px;
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anfedorov/pen/OgyLKp?editors=1100)

---

A third possible solution is to wrap the `separator`.

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with a similar issue and came across this old question. I have what I think is a better solution:

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/noleli/pen/exjqKR?editors=1100)

```
.separator {
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

The key thing here is **`align-self: stretch`**. Even if the rest of the flex items are aligned center, this will force this item to be the full size of the cross axis.

You can’t set a height using a percentage, so to get it down to 80% you can set margins.